# How to create a Shape using Path in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

i've been looking for some way to create a shape, and i found [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.windows.shapes.path.data(v=vs.105).aspx) this article about it,but i'm not sure how to use this, there's no tutorial to explain how to use each numbers inside of `Data`!

```
<Path Stroke="DarkGoldenRod" StrokeThickness="3"
Data="M 100,200 C 100,25 400,350 400,175 H 280"/>
```

I know this, "M" its the starter point, but its just beyond me!

Comment: what kind of shape you want to draw? if can yous blend for simple drawing like callout etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use blend to draw you shape. open your project in blend and draw whatever shape you want here the the tutorial

[Draw shapes and paths in Blend](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj170881(v=vs.120).aspx)

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks a lot!! @Muhammad